# Как проверять процесс через оригинальное имя по файлу

Tags: c#, процесс

Метод который получает исходное имя файла через процесс и сверяет его со списком процесс(а)ов. ( Это может быть `List<string>` и `string array` )

```
private static bool GetInternalNameProcess(Process p, string match)
{
   string internalname = p.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.InternalName;
   return internalname.ToLower().Equals(match.ToLower(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Создаю список массива `string array` процессов которые нужно проверять

```
string[] processes = new string[]
{
  "GameExplorer", "GameList", "GameReport", "GameAnalyzer"
};
```

Создаю метод который запускает проверку по процессам и если находит совпадения с `processes` то даёт результат.

```
public static void Start()
{
   foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
   {
     if (GetInternalNameProcess(proc, processes.Contains(proc.ProcessName)) // тут получаю ошибку!
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Найдены совпадения: " + proc.ProcessName + "");
     }
   }
}
```

> Ошибка CS1503 Аргумент 2: не удается преобразовать из "bool" в
>   "string"

Как мне правильно реализовать проверку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное так можно исправить ошибку

`string.Contains()` возвращает `bool`, а метод ждет `string match`

Можно сделать список

```csharp
List<string> processes = new List<string>
{
  "GameExplorer", "GameList", "GameReport", "GameAnalyzer"
};
```

Затем использовать Linq

```csharp
if (processes.Any(x => x == proc.ProcessName || GetInternalNameProcess(proc, x)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Найдены совпадения: " + proc.ProcessName + "");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо) Скажите а можно как-то использовать данную проверку без получения списка всех процесс через `Process.GetProcesses()` А сделать через `Process.GetProcessesByName("Тут список добавить");` P.S: Вам нужно добавить ещё одну `)` в конце в проверке `if`

Comment: @GooliveR не знаю, наверное нельзя. Ответ поправил, код писал с телефона, ошибся, спасибо!